# Why does creating an object when calling DB using Entity Framework result in "instances of abstract classes cannot be created" error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an **abstract** class `OrderDetail` and a class `Order` with this definition:

```
public class Order
{
    public OrderDetail Detail { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to query DB and get a list of Orders, but get "instances of abstract classes cannot be created" error. But if I test creating new Orders directly then there would be no problem.

Here's what I've tested so far:

**Pass cases**

```
var success1 = new Order();

var success2 = new Order() { Detail = null };

var success3 = db.Invoice.Select(_ => new Order()).ToList();
```

**Fail case**

```
var fail = db.Invoice.Select(_ => new Order() { Detail = null }).ToList();
```

I'm using .NET Framework 4.8 and Entity Framework 6.1.3.

Comment: Why is `OrderDetail` abstract in the first place? Seems rather odd.

Comment: @jmcilhinney it's the base class for a DB table implementing TPH. I'm trying to get that table as well when querying OrderDetails. The name might be a bit misleading in the example, let me update it.

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm using .NET Framework 4.8 and Entity Framework 6.1.3.

Comment: Please turn this into a [mre]. We can't reproduce this without guessing what the model + database look like.

Comment: @GertArnold The only thing not listed are the declaration of the database and the table Invoice's EntityTypeConfiguration. Should I include them?